# Jquery and farbtastic, updating background using colorwheel

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble figuring out how i can update the background of my website using the farbtastic color wheel.

i cant use a keyup() function or a change() function. i think i need to actually edit a callback using linkto.

this page 
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/03/22/jquery-color-picker-using-farbtastic-and-jquery-ui/
has an example but i dont understand how it is changing the color. i dont need all the extra fancy stuff, just simply changing the css background color.

I am just unsure how to call the farbtastic object and ask it the color. from there i can turn it into a var and edit the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax to create the farbtastic object (where "#picker" is the id of an empty div).  This will cause the page background color to be controlled by the wheel.

```
var p = $.farbtastic("#picker").linkTo("body");
```

Then, if needed, you can query the current color with

```
$("body").css("background-color");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the "farbtastic color wheel", but if your statement that you just need to "simply chang(e) the css background color" is true, then you can just use this method:

```
$(".MySelector").css("background-color","#000000");
```

If this isn't what you were looking for, please specify the detail in  your question.

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with this a bit yesterday to update the body's background. It's not the best solution, but [here's what I came up with](http://jsbin.com/EYegodUM/1/edit).

```
// Color Picker
$('#colorpicker').farbtastic('#color');
$('#colorpicker *, #color').on('keyup mousedown touchstart', function() {
  $('body').css('background-color', $("#color").val());
  $('#colorpicker').on('mousemove touchmove', function() {
    $('body').css('background-color', $("#color").val());
  });
});
```